# Multiple Recv Calls Socket C Programming

Tags: c, sockets

I am currently starting to learn to program sockets with the C programming language. I was wondering in the situation of a server that receives multiple messages, let's say I want to transfer a file from the client to the server. My question in this scenario is, do I have to call multiple times the `accept` function before calling each time the `recv` function? Or can I simply `accept` once the connection from the client side once and call multiple times `recv`?

Comment: You only call `accept()` once for each new inbound TCP connection, not once per packet.

Comment: Ok, but how do I know if I have received a message or not in `recv`?  Because it keeps listening to trash.

Comment: So you keep sending trash to it. Solution: don't.

Comment: 'how do I know if I have received a message or not in recv' - the returned value, (which I'm sure you're completely and correctly handling...?), is greater than 0 and indicates the number of bytes loaded into you buffer.  'it keeps listening to trash' - code pls.  Especially any use of strlen(), printf("%s"..) or similar calls that require char arrays that are guaranteed NUL-teminated...

Comment: As always, with debugging in a complex system, start by splitting up the problem.  Use wireshark, or similar, to find out if the problem is at the server, client or both.  LIke @EJP says, maybe you are sending trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using TCP connections ("socket programming" covers a wide variety of topics, but TCP is the most common) `accept` completes the connection via sockets between your application and a counterparty and sets up a different socket that should be used to transfer data.  The actual data transfer happens on this new socket.  So only call accept once per connection.
[See this page for a detailed description of what `accept` does.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)